# Gradle: espresso-core & appcompat failed to resolve; SDK installation doesn't have the extras

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've installed Android Studio and I've tried to create app.

My build.gradle module file is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a79231.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

[I have installed sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2t7D.jpg) and 26.0.0 is installed

I've got the errors:

1. Error:(23, 24) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0
   Install Repository and sync project
   Show in File
2. Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
   Install Repository and sync project
   Show in File
3. SDK installation [doesn't have the extras](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY3yf.jpg)
4. Event Log says: **Android SDK Tools Version 24.0.2 or later is required. Install latest SDK Tools**. Why? I have 26.

I tried to change espresso-core:2.0 to espresso-core:**2.2.2** and appcompat-v7:26.+ to appcompat-v7:**26.0.0** but the errors are the same. 
Also I tried to reinstall Android Studio. Result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the main build.gradle in repositories block

maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }